# Share a multichannel audio card between multiple apps?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

[I have a question on OBS's forum about getting that app specifically to share with something else](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/share-a-multichannel-audio-card-with-other-apps.133246/), but my question on *this* site comes at the problem from a different direction.  Instead of getting one specific app to not be exclusive, can I have Ubuntu itself allocate specific channels out of a multichannel card, to different apps that would otherwise take exclusive control of the entire card like OBS seems to?

Lubuntu 20.04, and the card in question is the 32-channel USB interface of a Behringer X32 digital sound board.  I can route any signal inside the X32 to any channel of the USB "sound card", so that routing can flow around some other requirements if needed.

I need OBS to receive a stereo pair, another recorder to receive 1 channel as mono (likely ffmpeg but not necessarily, as that recording also needs video, separately from OBS), and Ardour (a DAW) to receive 24 channels as multitrack.  All simultaneously.

Currently, my routing has the multitrack on the upper 24 (#'s 9-32), the stereo pair on 1&2, and the remaining 6 (#'s 3-8) silent so that OBS's insistent 7.1 downmixer doesn't get confused.  (except for the "subwoofer" track, which the downmixer ignores, and so I put the mono auxiliary soundtrack on that for now)  Again, I can rearrange all of those channel assignments if needed, but they must all be on the same 32-channel USB card.

[image]

Can I split those channels out to the respective apps that need them, so that each can have "exclusive" control of what it thinks is its assigned card with only the required channel count?

- OBS sees a stereo card and no longer insists on a 7.1 downmix.
- ffmpeg or whatever sees a mono card and doesn't need to filter channels on its own command line.
- Ardour sees 24-channel multitrack, or 28-29 channels if the solution allows me to consolidate like that.  (put the auxiliary soundtrack on #3 and give the rest to Ardour)  It's also okay, but not required, if Ardour sees all 32, but I don't want to *rely* on Ardour to make the others work.  So no passthrough in Ardour, even if it would technically solve the problem.

---

Update 2020-11-08:

I've gotten this far, and it appears to work so far, but to make it a permanent source in OBS instead of being tied to a specific scene (and forgetting to add it to one critical scene), it appears that I need it to be a PulseAudio device.  So how can I get Jack into a PA loopback that enumerates like the other PA devices?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was missing!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J-RQudJx30

Apparently, Google didn't think it was important to tell me that PulseAudio can now work directly with Jack.  Lots of forum questions about that exact problem with no answers...

Anyway, set it up according to the video, and PA creates a loopback device for Jack to connect to.  Jack then makes the connections like it's known for.

---

Essentially, the steps are:

1. Install Jack if it isn't already.
   `sudo apt install jackd`
2. Install the PulseAudio module for it.
   `sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-jack`
3. Edit PA's config file.
   `sudo nano /etc/pulse/default.pa`
   (the video uses vim, I prefer nano, you use what you like)
4. Add some lines under `### Load audio drivers statically...`
   `load-module module-jack-sink`
   `load-module module-jack-source`
5. Add some more lines under `### Make some devices default`
   `set-default-sink jack_out`
   `set-default-source jack_in`
6. Save and close the file.
7. Restart PulseAudio.  It might be easiest to reboot the whole machine, which also serves as the "reboot survival" test that you really should do anyway before you absolutely rely on it.

Now, when the system comes up and PulseAudio starts, it'll also start Jack and make it the default. ("fallback" in the familiar GUI controls)

You won't have any sound yet, because Jack defaults to nothing connected.  So open the Connections window, click an individual channel on each side, and then Connect at the bottom.  You should have sound now!  And your connection options are now in Jack, which is incredibly flexible.

[image]

If you want to make your connections survive a reboot, you can define a connections file and have that load on startup (Activate Patchbay persistence):

[image]

How to create that file is shown here, and it's not immediately intuitive:
https://www.rncbc.org/drupal/node/76

Instead of the Connect window, you need to use the Patchbay.  Why they're so similar and still separate, I don't know, nor why the easy-to-use Connect window doesn't just have a Save button that does all this for you.  But anyway, it is at least *possible*, and here's how:

[image]

You might notice that the connections here are no longer between individual channels, but between devices, and that not all devices have all of the channels that they could.  That's the first-glance-unintuitive difference in how this tool works compared to the other one.

To set up your persistent patches, first click the New button at the top left, and DON'T let it create a snapshot of existing connections.  It's not that smart, and will get it horribly wrong.  Instead, start with a blank slate, and create a set of custom devices that each have the specific channels that you want to connect as a group.

The Add button on each side brings up this window:

[image]

Give this new device a name, and choose which Client it uses.  (multiple devices can use the same Client, so don't worry about locking yourself out)  Then add only the channels ("Plugs") that this particular device is going to use.  All of these channels will be connected to all of the channels of another device, in the order that they appear here.  You can also rename each channel, but I think it's too easy to forget which is what if you customize it that far.

Create all of your devices or "channel groups" that way, on each side, and then connect them at the device level by clicking one each side and then the Connect button at the bottom.
(I also have some full-count devices that don't go anywhere, just to remind me of what I'm working with.)

[image]

NOW you can save that .xml file that the Setup window wants in "Activate Patchbay persistence".

[image]

And set up `qjackctl` to run on startup so that it can, in turn, load that file.  Userspace is fine; it doesn't need to be root.